# Use of earplugs while praying

Tags: salat

Sometime people around my neighborhood have parties and most of the time they use DJ for their enjoyment. As you all know it's too loud. How can i pray or even have wudu as it gets weaken listening to songs. So i thought a way i.e.  to have an earplug while praying.

**So, is it permissible to use earplug ?**

**If not, how do i concentrate in these drastic conditions?**

*I haven't practiced it yet.*

Comment: Good approach to answer all at a time.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood, you are just gonna use earplugs to stop the outside sound from getting to you. Well, there is nothing in the Quran or Sunnah that mentions that it is Haram. Just make sure that those earplugs won't distract you from salah.